# Discussion on proposed new tag

Tags: discussion, tags

I proposed a new [beginner](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beginner) tag at https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/55877914#55877914, but the right place to discuss it is here in Meta.

I already created that tag. Should we rename, delete, etc. it?

Suggestions and comments appreciated.

---

Although it can't be enforced, ideally the tag would be applied by the OQ him/herself.

Some folks wanting to help newbies might want to follow it.

Comment: There really weren't any existing appropriate tags for [the post that I created that tag for](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/17445/how-do-you-know-if-youre-on-a-10-meter-band).

Comment: I find it a good idea to discuss it here: +1.

Comment: The [beginner](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beginner) tag was removed from all questions. A tag can't be manually deleted, but it will go away soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That tag falls on important metrics, imho:

1. **utility**: great, now we'll have questions with that tag. How will that help? It doesn't describe a specific field of knowledge or skill necessary to answer.
2. **specificity**: what specifically would that tag describe? It's current description reads 
   "*Questions about getting started in amateur radio etc.*"
   The fact that it ends in "etc" probably means its not really especially specific. And what specifically is "getting started"? Does any question related to attaining a license qualify? Or only these specific to the lower classes? Am I a beginner, without license?
3. **universality**: I hinted at that above, but since this is *not* an expert discussion forum, you're supposed to ask questions about topics in which you're not an authority – hence, basically every question (aside from these we self-answer) would qualify for this tag!

So, my proposal would be to go through the list of currently tagged questions, re-tag to remove [beginner](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beginner) and then let the tag disappear.

Comment: Thank you, Marcus. What about a different name?

Comment: The current description was the first thing that came to mind.

Comment: hm, I think you might have a good idea, but we need to put down a couple cornerstones for what we want to achieve with this first. My, very utilarian, approach here would be: What do you want to *achieve, foster* with that tag? Soon as we know that, I'm sure we can agree on a name – basically, we could even make up a word, as long as we agree on its meaning :D

Comment: I don't know. Now I am out of ideas. Seemed like a good idea at the time. ;-)

Comment: Keep in mind that the reason why I created that tag was that there was no appropriate tag for that question. It was tagged [tag:jargon] by the OP, and I added two tags which barely apply.

Answer (score 3):

I find several of the arguments in answers to the meta.SE question that Kevin linked to in chat, [Should we be adding tags like [beginner] to questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59077/should-we-be-adding-tags-like-beginner-to-questions), to be interesting.  Of the four answers to that question, none argued in favor of having a `beginner` tag.

- People may find "beginner" offensive
- One person's "beginner" question is someone else's advanced question
- People might ignore interesting "beginner" questions

I agree with the argument that some people might find "beginner" to be offensive.  I propose that we change the `beginner` tag to `fundamentals`.

Comment: Oops, I thought that I accidentally deleted this, but it was you. I love [tag:fundamentals], but you can delete it again if you really want to.

Comment: I deleted it because I liked Marcus' argument for no such tag better, but on the other hand I'm glad that you undeleted it, because it's another option for the community.

Comment: I do like that, it gives the whole thing a direction. Maybe a bit broad. Fundamentals - of what? Wave propagation? Operating radios? Regulations? But I think this might be the direction of the term we could be going

Comment: @MarcusMüller Fundamentals of anything in the scope of hamSE, I suppose.

Comment: but that's pretty subjective, right? Like, I guess for me some things are super fundamental, because my path here was a rather theoretically-based one, whereas I might have real trouble doing something practical that's very fundamental for someone else?

Comment: If I say "fundamentals of electric circuits", that at least tries to agree on the scope a bit more!

Comment: I wish that I could have also marked your answer as accepted! :-)